# How do I stop my Android code from sending Arabic text when sending a date timestamp using the Java Util Date?

Tags: android, kotlin, date, timestamp, locale

In the app we are trying to send telemetry events to our API but users in Iran are sending through the timestamp formatted as such `"۲۰۲۲-۰۷-۰۶T۰۰:۰۳:۳۳.۳۹۰Z"`.

```
Exception while executing function:
LogTelemetry Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset: ۲۰۲۲-۰۷-۰۶T۰۰:۰۳:۳۳.۳۹۰Z.
Path 'appTimestamp', line 1, position 54.
```

The above is the exception the API is returning, the Locale is set to the Default, but I also have not been able to replicate the error by using the Arabic Locale

Below is the method used to get the timestamp

```kotlin
fun getGMTTImeStamp(): String {
    val formatter2 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault())
    formatter2.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
    val date = Date()
    return (formatter2.format(date) + "Z")
}
```

The data is being sent as a Json String. Example below:

```json
{   
    "action":6,
    "appTimestamp":"2022-07-08T08:36:45.454Z",
    "deviceId":"6d0ae55186cd5efc",
    "origin":3,
    "originId":"3c945925-53ac-4fbe-9266-210410903a85",
    "platform":0
}
```

The only information we have is the error above from the server and that the request was made in Iran

Comment: Please show us how you're sending the request to the API - at the moment we have no information about that at all. (We don't even know whether this is in JSON, XML, something else...)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought an Arabic locale was correct for Iran.  Try the 'fa_IR' locale ...

Comment: Indeed ... judging from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Comparison_of_different_numerals ... those >are< Persian numerals rather than Arabic numerals.

Comment: I suspect `Locale.getDefault()` to get the default locale of the device/JVM and I also suspect this default locale to be (somehow) Persian on devices used in Iran. But I'm not sure. Maybe try `Locale.ENGLISH` instead?

Comment: The `Exception` might be caused by the `Z` at the end of the Persian `String`… At least, it seems to be at *position 54* and the pattern in your `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't recognize it. From the fact that you obviously append a `Z` in `fun getGMTTImeStamp()`, I conclude that users from other regions transmit a timestamp without offset/zone. I would try to check for a `Z` in the first place and remove it if there is one.

Comment: First you stop using `SimpleDateFormat`. It's  a troublesome and outdated class. Second you use an `Instant` for your point in time. It's `toString` method generates the ISO 8601 format that you want. With no Arabic digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Locale to Locale.ENGLISH solved the problem was just difficult to test without setting my device language to Arabic